# Importing file from a different directory with duplicate file name

Tags: python, module, python-import, importerror

For example, if dir1 contains abc.py that imports config.py and dir2 also contains config.py, how do I import config.py from dir 2 into abc.py?

Here's a visual representation:

```
dir1/abc.py
     config.py
dir2/xyz.py
     config.py
```

I have tried this so far

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../dir2')
import config as lconfig 
print(sys.path)
print(dir(lconfig))
```

But it seems it imports the config.py from dir1 not from dir2

I confirmed by printing out sys.path.

also, print(dir(lconfig)) does return the path for dir2.

Comment: Instead of manipulating `sys.path` you should create a proper project structure with packages.

Comment: More on package relative imports , [link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent of `dir1` and `dir2` is in the path, you can do this:

```
import dir1.config
import dir2.config
print('dir1/config is: %s' % dir1.config)
print('dir2/config is: %s' % dir2.config)
```

If you like, you can give them shorter but meaningful names:

```
import dir1.config as config1
import dir2.config as config2
```